# Continuous integration for a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rubygems

I am currently in the process of developing a rails engine. It is stored on a private git.

I have a "test" application that uses the engine. In the gem file, I point to the git repository for the source of the gem. The logic behind this is I am the only developer on the project, but there are some people that help me test it and I need to provide those people with the latest version of my work, everyday.

I would like that every night, let's say at 3AM, that my test application update itself by fetching the latest version of the gem from my git.

I have two questions regarding this :

1. Is "automating" (cron job?) capistrano deployment the thing to do? Or is there something more specific I should look at?
2. Do I have to increment my gem version every day so my test application knows there is newer version, or it can simply pulls it from git everyday, no matter what the version is?

For the moment, what I'm doing is :

1. I increment the gem version in the git repository.
2. Using capistrano, I redeploy the application every night manually.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use:

- a shifting '`test`' tag in order for your deployment process to know what exact commit it has to test (shifting as in 'delete the old `test` tag, make a new one on the relevant commit to be tested for that daty, and then `git push`, and `git push --tags` in order to publish commits and then tags.)
- [`git note`](http://progit.org/2010/08/25/notes.html) in order to attach any information your process might need to the commit to be tested.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are telling me there. I evolved my setup a bit since I wrote the question : I now have a cron job doing the "cap deploy" every night, so it's now just a matter to increment the gem version in the repository. What would using a 'test' tag and git note would help me achieve?

Comment: @DominicGoulet: my answer was about deploying a specific commit in time (instead of whatever you have access to each night), and getting the gem version from notes attached to that commit instead of trying to extract it from a file.

Comment: Okay, but my original question was how to deploy what is in the git repository each and every night.

Comment: @DominicGoulet: I believe your cron job should be enough. I was simply pointing out ways to attach additional information without modifying existing commits.